# Dynamics CRM code popping up dialog in service

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

Given the following connection code:

```
    var serviceUri = "http://machine.co.za/CRM/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc";

    var clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials
    {
        Windows =
        {
            ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("SOMEUSER", "SOMEPASS", "DOMAIN")
        }
    };
    var organizationServiceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(serviceUri), null, clientCredentials, null);
    // This line of code pops up a dialog?
    var user = (WhoAmIResponse)organizationServiceProxy.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest());
    if (user.UserId == Guid.Empty)
        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(@"connection to {0} cannot be established.", crmConnection.ServiceUri));
    user.Dump();
```

If the supplied password is incorrect, the code pops up a credentials dialog.
Since the service does not have rights to interact with the desktop, the service halts as it cannot actually show a dialog.

How do I suppress the dialog, and have an exception get thrown instead. I am using dynamics 2011.

[image: The dialog that pops up!]

Comment: Where exactly is this code running?

Comment: I am not sure what you need. It's a service application on windows 2008 that does not have rights to interact with the desktop. It should not be attempting to popup a dialog.

Comment: Does it thrown an exception? Maybe wrap your code in a try/catch and see if something is thrown that you can deal with and log appropriately.

Comment: The code pops up a credentials dialog instead of throwing an exception. There is no exception until the popup dialog is cancelled.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the dialog that pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to take it as a given that the CRM dynamics `OrganizationServiceProxy` is hardwired to pop up a dialog.

There are no configuration options or flags that turn this behavior off.

Answer (score 0):

You may be mixing up usage of `CrmConnection`. It boils down to:

```
var conn = new ConnectionStringSettings("CRM", "Url=http://machine.co.za/CRM; Username=SOMEUSER; Password=SOMEPASS; Domain=SOMEDOMAIN")
var crmConnection = new CrmConnection(conn);
var crmService = new OrganizationService(crmConnection);
try
{
    // connection will actually happen here. anything goes wrong, exceptions will be thrown
    var user = crmService.Execute<WhoAmIResponse>(new WhoAmIRequest());
    user.Dump();
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // just a proof of concept
    // ex is of type MessageSecurityException if credentials are invalid
    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(@"connection to {0} cannot be established.", crmConnection.ServiceUri), ex);
}
```

Comment: I am using OrganizationServiceProxy, which is the web service interface.
I agree that the CrmConnection is superfluous, I have altered the question to reflect this.

Comment: it's OrganizationServiceProxy that is superfluous, not CrmConnection. Simplified connection exists for a reason